# Symfony2 - FOSUserBundle - Add _locale in url

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to overwrite default routing of FOSUserBundle for Symfony2 to get a result like this:

```
www.mysite.com/en/login
www.mysite.com/es/login
www.mysite.com/fr/login

www.mysite.com/en/profile
www.mysite.com/es/profile
www.mysite.com/fr/profile
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you rephrase this as a more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this link.](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/usage#prefixing-routes-before-the-locale) I think it is exactly what you need.

[...] to add a prefix before the _locale string (e.g. /admin/en/dashboard), you can add the “i18n_prefix” option.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
dashboard:
    ...
    options: { i18n_prefix: admin }
```